# SVN Tags as a trackback for Change Request

Tags: svn

I've asked this question before but now have more detail, so asking again.

We have code to send to production at least once every two weeks, as a requirement for audit, all the change requests should have information about the code that has been sent to prod.

The change management team has come up with a solution of writing scripts to import the SVN tags present in subversion into the Clear Quest, so that the developer who is creating the change request would choose the tag (from the drop-down populated with all tags) that is relevant for this specific move.

In order to fulfill this requirement, we are asked to tag every release with the Change Request Number, effectively creating many tags with CQ numbers which is clearly not useful from configuration management for the projects we're working on.

**My concerns are :**

> a) Is it okay to create so many tags just for the purpose of a track
> back URL with code? Would there be any issues w.r.t performance when a
> developer is trying to browse through the tags folder from IDE or
> tortoise svn client?
>
> b) Is it possible to create a track back URL with unique revision on a
> repository without specifying if it's in trunk or tag. We're are using
> VisualSVN Server.    e.g. http://abc.svn.com/myproject/p=100 which
> gets me changes of revision 100 (or the entire source code at revision
> 100). I would to know if this is a possibility using VisualSVN or any other tool to produce urls like http://svn.apache.org/r1460019 which would eventually resolve to branches/trunk/tags path for that revision.
>
> c) Is managing this requirement of a trackback URL to SVN better
> handled with revisions instead of tags, if you can provide some pros
> and cons of using SVN tags vs revisions, I would be grateful. **I do understand that tags are nothing but just named revisions.**

Answer (score 1):

I see small (unrelated) problem in this release-management: How you'll tag release, if during release cycle more than singe CR was implemented in code?

Back to your questions:

> Is it okay to create so many tags just for the purpose of a track back URL with code?

Yes

> Would there be any issues w.r.t performance when a developer is trying to browse through the tags folder from IDE or tortoise svn client?

*May be*, under some conditions (f.e "Refresh tree" in TSVN's RepoBrowser)

> Is it possible to create a track back URL with unique revision on a repository without specifying if it's in trunk or tag

Technically - yes: you create URL for the root of repository instead of subtree, which is valid revision URL.

Practically and technically - no. Path-part of URL is important for selecting **only needed part** of subtree (under the root you have a lot of "cheap copies" of your data, but they are cheap only inside repo, not in working copy) - *revision N of repository root* include **all branches and tags** in the *state of revision N*

> Is managing this requirement of a trackback URL to SVN better handled with revisions instead of tags

"It depends..." but, in common, no. repo/trunk@100 is not better or worse than repo/tags/CRN100, *just different*

**Edit**

For the URLs: you can use any *nice URL* in Web-Viewer of repository (ViewVCS|WebSVN), which you can get with rewrite|redirects and other Apache's methods, but these URLs can be used in any subversion operations: svn.apache.org/r1460019 show only for eyes changes in 1460019 (and Apache rewrites it into not-so-nice svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=r1460019), but in oder to see diff of this change in svn-client you have to know real URL of `subversion/branches/1.7.x/STATUS` in real repository

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however most of my concerns, still remain so. I have seen urls like http://svn.apache.org/r1460019 which resolves to a final trunk or branch path, so I suppose it is technically possible to give a unique revision link in the URL without specifying trunk or branch, however I'm looking at a solution within VisualSVN to create it instead of introducing a new component.

Comment: For the question "Is managing this requirement of a trackback URL to SVN better handled with revisions instead of tags" - when using URLs with revisions (like http://svn.apache.org/r1460019), we have the ability to merge the branch to trunk before deleting it without breaking the URL, if we start hardcoding unique tag urls, we would need to live with them forever as deleting would break the integrity of Change Control. Please correct me if my perception is wrong.

Comment: As far as multiple CRs in the same tag, we are planning to append multiple CQs in tag name :-O

Comment: @user1860370 - URLs for web-interface and for svn-client are different things: you can provide tricky-URL for web-browser, but not to SVN-client

Comment: apologies if I wasn't clear earlier, someone would look at the Change Ticket description and clicks on the SVN url to tag/revision with expectation to view the changes inside the browser, as the auditing team might not have an SVN client installed on their systems.

Comment: @user1860370 - for the Web-view you can use any tricks, it's a question of your repo-browser and Apache's guru (rewrite "nice" to "real"), ViewVCS of Apache team shows - it's possible